# Move method definition for template nested class outside declaration

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, nested

Is it possible to move method definition outside declaration?

```
template <typename T1>
class A
{
  template <bool T2>
  class B;

  template<>
  class B<true>
  {
    void f() { /* Do smg */ }
  }
  class B<false>
  {
    void f() { /* Do smg else */ }
  }
}
```

If I try to define f() outside class declaration, like this

```
template <typename T1>
template <>
void A<T1>::B<true>::f() { /* Do smg */ }
```

compiler gives error **C3855: template parameter T2 is incompatible with the declaration.**

Comment: On gcc 4.7.2, I can't get your top block to compile due to ``error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class A<T1>’``. Was it supposed to be an example of something that works? I understood so from the question...

Comment: VS2013 compiles top block without errors.

Comment: Not an expert on VS, but it's known to be a compiler with not that great compliance. My guess is that both blocks are technically illegal. g++'s error makes sense to me. In any case, am adding a VS tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot explicitly specialize a class member template of a non-specialized class template, from [temp.expl.spec]:

> In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears
>   in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain
>   unspecialized, except that the declaration **shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing
>   class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**.

Even the explicit specialiation of `B` inside of the definition of `A` is ill-formed. If you need to do such a thing, I would simply not use a member class template for `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to hack the system. Use partial specialization instead of explicit specialization, with fake template parameter, like this: http://goo.gl/yHRQwV

```
template <typename T1>
class A
{
public:  
  template <bool T2, typename = void>
  class B;

  template <typename Dummy>
  class B<true, Dummy>
  {
    public:
    void f1();
  };

  template <typename Dummy>
  class B<false, Dummy>
  {
    public:
    void f1();
  };
};

template <typename T1>
template <typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<true, Dummy>::f1()
{  
}

template <typename T1>
template <typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<false, Dummy>::f1()
{  
}

int main()
{
    A<int>::B<true> b1;
    b1.f1();

    A<int>::B<false> b2;
    b2.f1();
}
```

Not sure this is legal, but it works.

Actually, it does not solves my problem. In this case I can't add general methods f2(), f3() etc, to class B without specialization: http://goo.gl/wtIY0e

```
template <typename T1>
class A
{
public:  
  template <bool T2, typename = void>
  class B  
  {
    public:
    void f2();
    void f3();
  };

  template <typename Dummy>
  class B<true, Dummy>
  {
    public:
    void f1();
  };

  template <typename Dummy>
  class B<false, Dummy>
  {
    public:
    void f1();
  };
};

template <typename T1>
template <typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<true, Dummy>::f1()
{  
}

template <typename T1>
template <typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<false, Dummy>::f1()
{  
}

template <typename T1>
template <bool T2, typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<T2, Dummy>::f2()
{
}

template <typename T1>
template <bool T2, typename Dummy>
void A<T1>::B<T2, Dummy>::f3()
{
}

int main()
{
    A<int>::B<true> b1;
    b1.f1();
    b1.f2(); // error: A<int>::B<true> has no member f2
    b1.f3(); // error: A<int>::B<true> has no member f3
    A<int>::B<false> b2;
    b2.f1();
    b2.f2(); // error: A<int>::B<false> has no member f2
    b2.f3(); // error: A<int>::B<false> has no member f3
}
```

Finally, I found a solution that was looking for the whole day: **Static polymorphism** http://goo.gl/7yGZxM

```
template <typename T1>
struct A
{
  template<typename T2>
  struct BaseB
  {
    void f1();
    void f2();
    void f3();
  };

  struct B_true : BaseB<B_true>
  {
    void f1_impl();
  };

  struct B_false : BaseB<B_false>
  {
    void f1_impl();
  };
};

template <typename T1>
template<typename T2>
void A<T1>::BaseB<T2>::f1()
{
  static_cast<T2*>(this)->f1_impl();
}

template <typename T1>
template<typename T2>
void A<T1>::BaseB<T2>::f2()
{

}

template <typename T1>
template<typename T2>
void A<T1>::BaseB<T2>::f3()
{

}

template <typename T1>
void A<T1>::B_true::f1_impl()
{

}

template <typename T1>
void A<T1>::B_false::f1_impl()
{

}

int main()
{
  A<char>::B_true b_true;
  b_true.f1();
  b_true.f2();
  b_true.f3();

  A<char>::B_false b_false;
  b_false.f1();
  b_false.f2();
  b_false.f3();
}
```